# Laravel 5.2 redirect intended after register

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

I already got the redirect inteded working for my login flow. But I would like to navigate the user to the inteded page after he registers.

I already changed the behaviour to redirect to the register page if the user is not logged in and tries to access a protected route.

However, after the successful registration he is not redirected to the inteded route. After login it is working.

```
return redirect()->guest('/auth/register');
```

Answer (score 1):

in RegisterController.php

```
public function redirectTo(){
    $url = redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo)->getTargetUrl();
    return $url;
}
```

If there is an intention, it will be directed to it, otherwise it will be directed to the url saved in the $ redirectTo property

Comment: I tried this, but it still sends me to the default page set in the $redirectTo variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `$redirectPath` variable. Simply add below line to `AuthController` class inside your `Auth/AuthController.php`

`protected $redirectPath= '/yourURL';`

The redirect path above will be used for successful login and successful registration.

If you are just wanting to redirect after registration and not login then you would need to customise the `postRegister()` function:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
   $validator = $this->registrar->validator($request->all());
   if ($validator->fails())
   {
       $this->throwValidationException(
           $request, $validator
       );
   }
   $this->auth->login($this->registrar->create($request->all()));     
   //Set your redirect path below
   return redirect('/plan');
}
```

Comment: thanks - but the problem is that i want to go to the intended page - for example someone tries to access /plans/5 or /plans/3 - he will be forced to login / register. In both cases I want to route them to the plan directly

Comment: @FrankProvost Ah I see, so when they hit the URI `/plans/{id}` you want them to be able to reach the page whether they are logged in or not?

Comment: Actually no :) the workflow is like this: Unregistered User calls /plans/{id} -> gets redirected to register page -> registers -> gets redirected to intended /plans/{id} 
This flow is working perfeclty fine with login, but not with register

Answer (score 0):

You could set the intended page as a session var.

```
return redirect()->guest('/auth/register')->with('intendedUrl', $request->path());
```

Then just pick it up again after registration.

```
$intendedUrl = $request->session()->get('intendedUrl');
```

Don't forget to clear the session var though.

Answer (score 0):

```
 return redirect()->intended('/auth/register');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.5 you need to remove `$redirectTo` variable and create a `redirectTo` function instead in the user register controller as follow:

```
public function redirectTo()
{
    $intended = Session::get('url.intended');

    if (!empty($intended)) {
        Session::forget('url.intended');
        return $intended;
    }

    return 'YOUR_NORMAL_URL';
}
```

Make sure the register controller uses `RegistersUsers`. If you check `RedirectsUsers` trait which is used in `RegistersUsers` trait there is this function:

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {
        return $this->redirectTo();
    }

    return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
}
```

which checks for `redirectTo` function first.

Hope this is helpful for someone.